# Reinstalling all base fedora packages from live USB or distro repair

Tags: fedora, system-installation

I am an idiot.

I was browsing the internet as was told to install media codecs. I followed [this](https://ostechnix.com/how-to-install-multimedia-codecs-in-fedora-linux/#:%7E:text=After%20enabling%20RPM%20Fusion%2C%20run%20the%20following%20commands,command%20doesn%27t%20work%2C%20try%20the%20following%20command%20instead%3A?msclkid=d65db7ebc58411eca6c9af71360b1635) guide and ran the below

```
sudo dnf install gstreamer1-plugins-{bad-\*,good-\*,base} gstreamer1-plugin-openh264 gstreamer1-libav --exclude=gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-devel
```

It installed around 500MB worth packages which didn't help my issue so I ran the same command again with a remove not an install.

This removed ~ 2GB worth of packages INCLUDING my desktop environment (Cinnamon)

I have the fedora 36 live ISO I used to install the system.

How can I reinstall all packages from the live ISO onto my broken install?

### Or any other fixes

FYI I tried to run

> sudo dnf history undo 25

where 25 was my transaction id but it failed and couldn't reinstall anything.

Comment: Reinstalling from scratch could be the easiest solution.

Comment: Does `dnf history rollback ...` have any success?

Comment: No, same as without rollback namely cannot find missing packages.

Comment: I really do not want to nuke my HDD though as I have a dualbooted windows install and liscened software both win/lin I cannot easily reactivate.

Comment: I will of course take steps so this cant happen again (btrfs snapshots)?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my system thanks the below instructions [source](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/QA:Testcase_partitioning_custom_btrfs_preserve_home)

> In Installation Destination, click Custom under Storage Configuration
> Under New mount points will use the following partitioning scheme, select Btrfs (otherwise you'll not be able to create a new subvolume for / mountpoint later due to some poor UI decisions (bugzilla)).
> Locate the previous Fedora installation, click on it to reveal existing mount points for reuse
> If present, select /boot/efi or BIOS Boot mount point; then on the right hand side at the top, find Mount Point field, type in /boot/efi, click Update Settings button.
> Select /boot mount point; then on the right hand side at the top, find Mount Point field, type in /boot, check the Reformat box, click Update Settings button.
> Select /home mount point; then on the right hand side at the top, find Mount Point field, type in /home, click Update Settings button.
> Click + button to create a new / mount point (NOTE: this is required to be a new subvolume. Reformat will be checked, cannot be unchecked, but the underlying Btrfs is not reformatted. Click Update Settings button. Click Done
> Perform the installation and reboot the machine.

It worked perfectly and I am so happy.

Comment: Congratulations of finding the solution yourself. However, please note that [link-only answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) are discouraged, as the link may become invalid or the linked content change. Please edit your answer to include at least a summary of the linked explanation.